# Geronimo server could not fully load class: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet

Tags: jsf-2, geronimo

I got a problem with Geronimo server 3.0.
When I deployed file war to server. It occur an error like this.

```
The application was not deployed.
Could not fully load class: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
due to:javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet$HttpMethod
in classLoader: 
GeronimoClassLoader[com.workingmanage.CheckingSystem-DEPLOYMENT_1.0.0 [378]]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not fully load class: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
due to:javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet$HttpMethod
in classLoader: 
GeronimoClassLoader[com.workingmanage.CheckingSystem-DEPLOYMENT_1.0.0 [378]]
at org.apache.xbean.finder.ClassFinder.(ClassFinder.java:136)
at org.apache.geronimo.web25.deployment.AbstractWebModuleBuilder.createWebAppClassFinder(AbstractWebModuleBuilder.java:663)
at org.apache.geronimo.web25.deployment.AbstractWebModuleBuilder.configureBasicWebModuleAttributes(AbstractWebModuleBuilder.java:698)
at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.deployment.TomcatModuleBuilder.addGBeans(TomcatModuleBuilder.java:476)
at org.apache.geronimo.j2ee.deployment.SwitchingModuleBuilder.addGBeans(SwitchingModuleBuilder.java:174)
at org.apache.geronimo.j2ee.deployment.EARConfigBuilder.buildConfiguration(EARConfigBuilder.java:764)
at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:281)
at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:145)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ReflectionMethodInvoker.java:34)
at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanOperation.invoke(GBeanOperation.java:131)
at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.invoke(GBeanInstance.java:883)
at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.invoke(BasicKernel.java:245)
at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.plugin.local.AbstractDeployCommand.doDeploy(AbstractDeployCommand.java:116)
at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.plugin.local.DistributeCommand.run(DistributeCommand.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**I already define jsf-api and jsf-impl library in pom.xml file**

And this is my POM file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>****</groupId>
<artifactId>****</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>*** Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>4.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.secure.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.secure.version>
    <testng.version>6.8.7</testng.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <dbunit.version>2.4.9</dbunit.version>
    <rewrite-servlet.version>2.0.10.Final</rewrite-servlet.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>Prime Repo</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${rewrite-servlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <!-- DBUnit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.175</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- unit test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- PrimeFaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- c3p0 dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jt400</groupId>
        <artifactId>jt400-full</artifactId>
        <version>5.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.secure.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.secure.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.secure.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- for JSF 2.x -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
        <version>${rewrite-servlet.version}</version>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- Quart scheduler -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JMS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test NG -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>CheckingSystem</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:postgresql://***.***.**.**:5432/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
            <sonar.jdbc.username>***</sonar.jdbc.username>
            <sonar.jdbc.password>***</sonar.jdbc.password>
            <sonar.jdbc.driver>org.postgresql.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driver>
            <sonar.host.url>http://***.***.**.**:9000/sonar/</sonar.host.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

My web.xml file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>PrimeFaces Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
            /WEB-INF/securityContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>default.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
     <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
      </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should make some change as bellow:

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">
```

geronimo.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/web-2.0.1"
         xmlns:nam="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/naming-1.2"
         xmlns:sec="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/security-2.0"
         xmlns:sys="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/deployment-1.2">
    <sys:environment>
        <sys:moduleId>
            <sys:groupId>com.test</sys:groupId>
            <sys:artifactId>my-web</sys:artifactId>
            <sys:version>1.0.0</sys:version>
            <sys:type>car</sys:type>
        </sys:moduleId>
        <sys:dependencies>
        </sys:dependencies>
        <sys:import-package>!org.apache.commons.logging.*</sys:import-package>
        <sys:import-package>!javax.faces*</sys:import-package>
        <sys:import-package>!org.apache.myfaces*</sys:import-package>
        <!--
        <sys:hidden-classes>
            <sys:filter>javax.faces</sys:filter>
        </sys:hidden-classes>
        <sys:inverse-classloading />
        -->
    </sys:environment>
    <context-root>/my-web</context-root>
</web-app>
```